# javascript promises recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, es6-promise

I have a async recursive function which returns promise if there is more work to do or returns result array otherwise. In case where no recursion is involved it correctly return the array but when recursion is there the array is undefined. The code is

```
function foo(filepath) {

  var resultArr = [];

  function doo(file) {
        return asyncOperation(file).then(resp => {
            resultArr.push(resp.data);
            if (resp.pages) {
                var pages = resp.pages.split(',');
                pages.forEach(page => {
                    return doo(page);
                });
            } else {
                return resultArr;
            }
        });
    }

    return doo(filepath);
}
```

And the way this is called

```
foo(abcfile).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

If I pass abcfile which has no resp.pages, I get result array, but there are resp.pages, then the result array is undefined.

Comment: What are you hoping to do with the `pages` data? You aren't returning anything in the `if (resp.pages)` block and the return used in the function passed to `forEach` doesn't do anything

Comment: When `resp.pages` is truth, you return nothing, which equals `return undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're just missing a returned promise within the `if (resp.pages)` block

```
if (resp.pages) {
    return Promise.all(resp.pages.split(',').map(page => doo(page)))
        .then(pagesArr => {
            return resultArr.concat(...pagesArr)
        })
}
```

---

I'm thinking there may be an issue with scoping `resultArr` outside the `doo` function so maybe try this

```
function foo(filepath) {
    function doo(file) {
        return asyncOperation(file).then(resp => {
            const resultArr = [ resp.data ]
            if (resp.pages) {
                return Promise.all(resp.pages.split(',').map(page => doo(page)))
                    .then(pagesArr => resultArr.concat(...pagesArr))
            } else {
                return resultArr
            }
        })
    }

    return doo(filePath)
}
```

---

To explain the use of the spread-operator, look at it this way...

Say you have three pages for a file `top`; `page1`, `page2` and `page3` and each of those resolves with a couple of sub-pages each, the `pagesArr` would look like

```
[
  ['page1', 'page1a', 'page1b'],
  ['page2', 'page2a', 'page2b'],
  ['page3', 'page3a', 'page3b']
]
```

and `resultArr` so far looks like

```
['top']
```

If you use `concat` without the spread operator, you'd end up with

```
[
  "top",
  [
    "page1",
    "page1a",
    "page1b"
  ],
  [
    "page2",
    "page2a",
    "page2b"
  ],
  [
    "page3",
    "page3a",
    "page3b"
  ]
]
```

But with the spread, you get

```
[
  "top",
  "page1",
  "page1a",
  "page1b",
  "page2",
  "page2a",
  "page2b",
  "page3",
  "page3a",
  "page3b"
]
```

Comment: @Phil I think ya scope of the array might be issue along with promises

Comment: do i need to use the spread operator ..what does it do? @Phil

Comment: @ams I've added an explanation to my answer. If this doesn't work for you, could you provide an example of the desired output format?

Comment: Thanks that explains ..I get an error with ... operator ..SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...I have node 4.4.7 @Phil

Comment: @Phil nice analysis of the problem – and nice solution too. Parallel processing of the sub-pages is definitely a good way to go as long as **1.** there are no circular references (unless you have some elegant solution for that, too! I can't think of one ...) and **2.** pages do not have a significantly large number of sub-pages. If 5 pages, each had 5 pages, that each had 5 pages, you'd be up to *hundreds* of simultaneous requests. Might be good to offer/suggest a queue that can be limited/throttled.

Comment: @naomik yup, gotta worry about the stack size with all those recursive calls too

Comment: @ams that's a **very** old version of Node. I assumed you'd be using something more recent due to the [tag:es6-promises] tag

Answer (score 1):

To verify this works, I'll make a `fake` dataset, and a `fakeAsyncOperation` which reads data from the dataset asynchronously. To model your data closely, each query from the fake dataset returns a response with `data` and `pages` fields.

```
let fake = new Map([
  ['root',    {data: 'root',    pages: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}],
  ['a',       {data: 'a',       pages: ['a/a', 'a/a']}],
  ['a/a',     {data: 'a/a',     pages: []}],
  ['a/b',     {data: 'a/b',     pages: ['a/b/a']}],
  ['a/b/a',   {data: 'a/b/a',   pages: []}],
  ['b',       {data: 'b',       pages: ['b/a']}],
  ['b/a',     {data: 'b/a',     pages: ['b/a/a']}],
  ['b/a/a',   {data: 'b/a/a',   pages: ['b/a/a/a']}],
  ['b/a/a/a', {data: 'b/a/a/a', pages: []}],
  ['c',       {data: 'c',       pages: ['c/a', 'c/b', 'c/c', 'c/d']}],
  ['c/a',     {data: 'c/a',     pages: []}],
  ['c/b',     {data: 'c/b',     pages: []}],
  ['c/c',     {data: 'c/c',     pages: []}],
  ['c/d',     {data: 'c/d',     pages: []}],
  ['d',       {data: 'd',       pages: []}]
]);

let fakeAsyncOperation = (page) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 100, fake.get(page))
  })
}
```

Next we have your `foo` function. I've renamed `doo` to `enqueue` because it works like a queue. It has two parameters: `acc` for keeping track of the accumulated data, and `xs` (destructured) which is the items in the queue.

I've used the new `async/await` syntax that makes it particularly nice for dealing with this. We don't have to manually construct any Promises or deal with any manual `.then` chaining.

I made liberal use of the spread syntax in the recursive call because I its readability, but you could easily replace these for `concat` calls `acc.concat([data])` and `xs.concat(pages)` if you like that more. – this is functional programming, so just pick an immutable operation you like and use that.

Lastly, unlike other answers that use `Promise.all` this will process each page in *series*. If a page were to have 50 subpages, `Promise.all` would attempt to make 50 requests in *parallel* and that may be undesired. Converting the program from parallel to serial is not necessarily straightforward, so that is the reason for providing this answer.

```
function foo (page) {
  async function enqueue (acc, [x,...xs]) {
    if (x === undefined)
      return acc
    else {
      let {data, pages} = await fakeAsyncOperation(x)
      return enqueue([...acc, data], [...xs, ...pages])
    }
  }
  return enqueue([], [page])
}

foo('root').then(pages => console.log(pages))
```

Output

```
[ 'root',
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'a/a',
  'a/a',
  'b/a',
  'c/a',
  'c/b',
  'c/c',
  'c/d',
  'b/a/a',
  'b/a/a/a' ]
```

---

Remarks

I'm happy that the `foo` function in my solution is not too far off from your original – I think you'll appreciate that. They both use an inner auxiliary function for looping and approach the problem in a similar way. `async/await` keeps the code nice an flat and highly readable (imo). Overall, I think this is an excellent solution for a somewhat complex problem.

Oh, and don't forget about **circular references**. There are no circular references in my dataset, but if page `'a'` were to have `pages: ['b']` and page `'b'` had `pages: ['a']`, you can expect infinite recursion. Because this answer processes the pages serially, this would be a very easy to fix (by checking the accumulated value `acc` for an existing page identifier). This is much trickier (and out-of-scope of this answer) to handle when processing the pages in parallel.

Comment: Great answer and it's nice to see `async` and `await` becoming the norm. I assumed that OP's code is attempting to navigate a file-system so, if we ignore links (symlinks), circular references are *probably* not an issue. Also, your StackOverflow formatting skiils are off the chain!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Phil ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is mixing async/sync operations in `if (resp.pages)` branch. Basically you'll have to return promise from then callback if you want the promise chain to work as expected.

In addition to Phil's answer, if you want to execute pages in order/sequence

```
if (resp.pages) {
  var pages = resp.pages.split(',');
  return pages.reduce(function(p, page) {
    return p.then(function() {
        return doo(page);
    });
  }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

Comment: That's pretty cool and a good addition if OP's `asyncOperation` cannot execute multiple requests in parallel but you aren't combining the results in any way

Answer (score -1):

The issue is you don't return anything when there's pages.

```
function foo(filepath) {

  var resultArr = [];

  function doo(file, promises) {
        let promise = asyncOperation(file).then(resp => {
            resultArr.push(resp.data);
            if (resp.pages) {
                var pages = resp.pages.split(',');
                var pagePromises = [];
                pages.forEach(page => {
                    return doo(page, pagePromises);
                });

                //Return the pages
                return pagePromises;
            } else {
                return resultArr;
            }
        });

        //They want it added
        if ( promises ) { promises.push( promise ); }

        //Just return normally
        else { return promise; }
    }

    return doo(filepath);
}
```

Comment: This won't wait for the recursive async operations